# ¿Es posible evitar que se destruyan los datos cargados de un ViewModel cuando se cierra su respectivo fragmento?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewmodel

Tengo 5 fragmentos cada uno con sus respectivos ViewModel que los lanzo utilizando un NavHostFragment. En 3 de ellos cargo en otro hilo usando Mutable Live Data datos de uso de la clase NetworkStatsManager. Todo funciona correctamente.
**El Problema**
Como quizás deban saber cargar datos de la clase NetworkStatsManager toma su tiempo, quizás uno o dos segundos, dependiendo del dispositivo, entonces cada vez que él usuario entra en uno de estos 3 fragmentos, sale y vuelve a entrar tiene que esperar cada vez a que se carguen los datos nuevamente. Entonces ahí va mi pregunta ¿Es posible de algún modo extender el ciclo de vida de los ViewModel para que una vez el usuario haya iniciado su respectivo fragmento se mantengan los datos cargados aún cuando el fragmento sea destruido? Agradecido de cualquier ayuda que me puedan dar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que la información del View Model sobreviva después de destruirse el fragmento (entendiendo que el Acivity es el mismo), lo que puedes optar es por usar el Activity como ViewModelStoreOwner, Lo que hara que mientras el Activity sea el mismo tu podrás declarar el ViewModelProvider sobre el activity con tu mismo viewmodel (en este caso CustomViewModel) y el contenido seguira ai.

```
// Creo que tendras Algo asi dentro del fragmento  
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CustomViewModel::class.java)

// Lo puedes puedes cambiar por 
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(CustomViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias David Cruz. Esto responde mi pregunta inicial. Pero creo que debo crear otra pregunta ya que pensando mejor necesito otro enfoque en mi app. En realidad lo que necesito es mantener los fragmentos vivos cuando se navega a otro fragmento. Así no se recrea ningún fragmento que ya haya sigo creado y se mantendrían las selecciones y posiciones de los recycler view de los usuarios. ¿Será posible hacerlo de algún modo usando el componente de navegación de Google sin usar uno personalizado?

Comment: Para los que estén interesados en darme alguna ayuda, aquí les dejo el enlace a la nueva pregunta que creé con este problema. Gracias https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/382561/navegar-a-otro-fragmento-sin-recrearlo-usando-el-componente-de-navegación-de-goo#

Comment: EJV, Navigation component siempre va a reemplazar el fragmento, si lo quieres añadir en su lugar vas a tener que que crear una extension del FragmentNavigator: mira aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52716962/add-not-replace-fragment-with-navigation-architecture-component