# Navegar a otro fragmento sin recrearlo usando el componente de navegación de Google

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, navigationview

Comprendo que la manera en que funciona el componente de navegación moderno de Google hace que se destruya el fragmento actual una vez que navegamos a otro fragmento usando un bottomnavigationview.

**¿Existe la posibilidad de mantener vivos los fragmentos y no recrear vez tras vez cada fragmento cuando se navegue nuevamente hacia el mismo?**

El por qué de esta pregunta es el siguiente. Conozco que existe la posibilidad de guardar los datos almacenados en el ViewModel y como ya [pregunté en este mismo sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/382296/es-posible-evitar-que-se-destruyan-los-datos-cargados-de-un-viewmodel-cuando-se) podemos pasarle el dueño del ciclo de vida de la única actividad en la que se mostrarán los fragmentos. Y también he visto algunas respuestas a preguntas similares que plantean usar savedInstanceState para almacenar cada vez todo y volverlo a recargar. Pero en realidad no creo que deba ser necesario hacer todo esto. Simplemente debe haber alguna manera de dejar los fragmentos ya iniciados en segundo plano y si ya están ahí en vez de volverlos a crear sería solo traerlos al frente nuevamente. Y lógicamente en el destroy de la actividad que también se eliminen estos fragmentos.

Así no importa si el usuario navegó hacia otro fragmento, las posiciones de los RecyclerView, las selecciones de los Spinner que realizó, la información cargada, en fin, todo se mantendría exactamente igual que cuando dejó ese fragmento creado para navegar a otro y luego regresa a el mismo.

Espero hacerme entender. Agradezco mucho cualquier ayuda u orientación que me puedan dar. Un detalle más, **no conozco Kotlin, solo se leer Java.** Disculpen las molestias que esto pueda ocasionar

Comment: te deje el comentario en la pregutna anterior pero te lo dejo aqui tambien: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52716962/add-not-replace-fragment-with-navigation-architecture-component

Comment: Gracias nuevamente por tu ayuda David.Cruz al parecer no es posible lograr esto solamente usando el componente de navegación de Google. Tendré que crear uno personalizado. He visto en respuestas a otras preguntas similares ejemplos de cómo hacerlo usando Java. En cuanto tenga uno hecho que funcione lo pondré acá  para que quizás pueda servirle de ayuda a otra persona que como yo también tenga este problema. Gracias a todos